# Correct way to inline style in JSX

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to do inline style for which following is working

```
 <dt className='some-element' style={{backgroundColor : '#1a1a1a', fill: '#1a1a1a'}}>
```

Now I am trying to change the hex value every time so trying to have something like

```
let styleConfig = `backgroundColor : '${someColor}', fill: '${someColor}'`
<dt className='some-element' style={{styleConfig}}>
```

But I am not getting seeing style being applied as the first one nor I get any console error.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

React components' attributes expect a value wrapped in quotes for strings or curly brackets (for other values and variables).

The 1st pair of curly brackets in `style={{backgroundColor : '#1a1a1a', fill: '#1a1a1a'}}` is the attribute value wrapper, and the 2nd is part of the object you pass as a value to the attribute - `{backgroundColor : '#1a1a1a', fill: '#1a1a1a'}`

Because of [ES6 shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015), this is what you actually get, when you pass the variable `styleConfig` into two pairs of curly brackets `style={{styleConfig}}`:

```
style={{ styleConfig: `backgroundColor : '${someColor}', fill: '${someColor}'` }}
```

In addition `styleConfig` should be an object, and not a string, because the `style` attribute expects an [object of style properties](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#style).

Try this:

```
let styleConfig = { backgroundColor : 'red', fill: 'blue' } // create an object of style properties 
<dt className='some-element' style={styleConfig}> // use a single pair of curly brackets
```

Comment: hmm .. getting error "identifier or string literal or numeric literal expected" for postion between { and `background..

Comment: Update the `styleConfig` object in the example. You don't actually need a template literal. Use a string or a variable that contains a string as the color name/value.

Comment: Hy @OriDrori I want to add image in background instead of fix color will you please help me out. Thank you